# fitting a complex function in matlab using "lsqcurvefit"

Tags: matlab

I have a complex function that I want to fit to some real data. The function is of the form:

`Y = -2*imag((A-B)/(A+2*B))`   ...................(1)

where

"imag" means imaginary part of the equation
`A = a - (b/X)*1i`             .....................(2)
`B = c - (d/X)*1i`             .....................(3)

Y has both imaginary and real parts. But it's the imaginary part that is relevant to my problem. How do I derive the values of a,b,c and d  by fitting equation (1) to real experimental data? I have tried to use "lsqcurvefit" but it keeps returning the same starting values I put in! I am sure I must have missed something important.

Please kindly simplify your answers as much as possible as I'm still new at MATLAB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To run lsqcurvefit on your function, you can first create a file called f.m that contains:

```
function Y = f(params,X)

a = params(1);
b = params(2);
c = params(3);
d = params(4);

A = a - ((b ./ X) .* 1i);
B = c - ((d ./ X) .* 1i);

Y = 2 .* imag((A - B)./(A + 2*B));
```

Then call lsqcurvefit for this function and plot the results:

```
startParams = [1, 2, 3, 4];
x = 1:100;
y = f(startParams, x);
fitParams = lsqcurvefit(@f, startParams+1, x, y)

yFit = f(fitParams, x);
plot(x, y, 'b*')
hold on
plot(X, yFit, 'r')
legend('data','fit')
```

Comment: I adapted your sample to real data and a new function: function F = f1(params,xdata)
a = params(1); % e_mem
b = params(2); % s_mem
c = params(3); % e_int
d = params(4); % s_int
em = 80*8.854e-12; D = 6e-9; r =5e-6; sm = 5.6e-2; R = ((r+D)/r);
    E_mem = a - (b*1i)./(2*pi*xdata); % complex E_mem
    E_int = c - (d*1i)./(2*pi*xdata); % complex E_int
    E_m = em - (sm*1i)./(2*pi*xdata);         %  complex E_m
    E_p = (R^3 + 2*(E_int - E_mem)./(E_int + 2*E_mem))./(R^3 - (E_int - E_mem)./(E_int + 2*E_mem));% complex E_p
    
 F = -7.59e-8*imag((E_p-E_m)./(E_p+2*E_m));

end

Comment: Then I run the solver. But I got the same starting values even when I change them. Where lies the problem?
startParams = [8.2e-5, 7.79e-10, 4.42e-10, 0.1];

xdata = [1e4;1.8e4;3.00e4;5.50e4;1e5;1.8e5;3.1e5;5.5e5;1e6;1.8e6;3e6;5.5e6;1e7;1.8e7;3e7;5.5e7;1e8];

ydata= 0.81*([-0.15;-0.25;-0.41;-0.72;-1.1;-1.35;-1.3;-1;-0.61;-0.35;-0.2;0;0.01;0.35;0.55;0.78;0.8]);

fitParams = lsqcurvefit(@f1, startParams, xdata, ydata)

yFit = f1(fitParams, xdata);
semilogx(xdata, ydata, 'b*')
hold on
semilogx(xdata, yFit, 'r')
legend('data','fit').        % thanks

Comment: Do the starting parameters give a good fit? What if you start with parameters that are way off? Take a look at the residuals. You can change MaxIter, MaxFunEvals, TolX, and TolFun in the Options input argument to make lsqcurvefit look for a different results.  I don't have it in front of me at the moment. (Consider accepting the answer if it's helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks Molly. I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I took a look.  You need starting parameters that are closer to the actual values.

Comment: You've  been really helpful. I get the same starting parameters I put in even after changing them. I know what my answers should look like but I was wondering if I didn't know, wouldn't I be able to fit the data? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to plot the function you included above (not sure I got the formatting correct) and it looked like a straight line compared to your data. It didn't seem to be very sensitive to changed in the parameters either. If that's really the case, the curve fitting algorithm isn't going to find a good fit. Generally, you have to have some idea of what your fit should look like to start. You have to give a reasonable starting point or it won't converge.

Comment: Thanks Molly. I got the same straight line compared to my data points. I know the exact range where my answers should lie but the straight line is persistent. Is there any other way around this?